# DocusignAPi neither Phone Authentication nor Social ID Authentication working

Tags: docusignapi

I have a docusign developer account in demo.docusign.net. I am integrating my application with docusign through SOAP API. I am trying to Authenticate using Phone and AnySocialID. But it is not asking for any authentication. Please find below the XML and could you please let me know whats wrong in it. It is not prompting for Phone call or not asking any social ID authentication.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateAndSendEnvelope xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
      <Envelope>
        <AccountId>a6cff121-fb11-4a50-a2fb-9ce50ba70f7c</AccountId>
        <Documents>
          <Document>
            <ID>LEASE AGREEMENT</ID>
            <Name>838.doc</Name>
            <PDFBytes>BBBXXX</PDFBytes>
            <FileExtension>.doc</FileExtension>
          </Document>
        </Documents>
        <Recipients>
          <Recipient>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <UserName>MUKES OUTLOOK</UserName>
            <Email>M.AGRAWAL@OUTLOOK.COM</Email>
            <Type>Signer</Type>
            <AccessCode xsi:nil="true" />
            <PhoneAuthentication>
              <RecipMayProvideNumber>true</RecipMayProvideNumber>
              <RequireIDLookup>true</RequireIDLookup>
              <IDCheckConfigurationName>Phone Auth $</IDCheckConfigurationName>
            </PhoneAuthentication>
            <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
            <RoleName>Lessee</RoleName>
          </Recipient>
          <Recipient>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <UserName>MUK TOPTAL</UserName>
            <Email>MUKESH@TOPTAL.COM</Email>
            <Type>Signer</Type>
            <AccessCode xsi:nil="true" />
            <AnySocialIDRecipientAuthentication>true</AnySocialIDRecipientAuthentication>
            <RoutingOrder>2</RoutingOrder>
            <RoleName>Guarantor</RoleName>
          </Recipient>
        </Recipients>
        <Tabs>
          <Tab>
            <DocumentID>LEASE AGREEMENT</DocumentID>
            <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
            <AnchorTabItem>
              <AnchorTabString>??CS1!</AnchorTabString>
              <Unit>Cms</Unit>
              <IgnoreIfNotPresent>false</IgnoreIfNotPresent>
            </AnchorTabItem>
            <Type>SignHere</Type>
            <Name>Lessee Signature 1</Name>
          </Tab>
          <Tab>
            <DocumentID>LEASE AGREEMENT</DocumentID>
            <RecipientID>2</RecipientID>
            <AnchorTabItem>
              <AnchorTabString>??GS1!</AnchorTabString>
              <Unit>Cms</Unit>
              <IgnoreIfNotPresent>false</IgnoreIfNotPresent>
            </AnchorTabItem>
            <Type>SignHere</Type>
            <Name>Guarantor Signature 2</Name>
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
        <Subject>Subject</Subject>
        <EmailBlurb>Body</EmailBlurb>
      </Envelope>
    </CreateAndSendEnvelope>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell your SOAP request looks right, it's possible these advanced forms of recipient authentication are not enabled in the developer sandbox accounts because I think they actually cost DocuSign money each time they are used (whether in demo or production).

Please reach out to your DocuSign account manager to have them enabled it or support if you don't have an AM yet.

Comment: I contacted support(Support <support@docusign.com>), but they could not help me. Could you please help me or redirect me to proper place? Following is the response from support:  We apologize if you're having difficulties. However, our department can't help when the issue is related to an integration process. Only our developers can help you with that by posting it to their page and wait for their responses.

Best regards,

AJ G.
DocuSign Customer Support
866.219.4318